# Prepared Statements in C++ using mssql database

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, odbc, prepared-statement

I opened my database with the CDatabase class.

```
if (!database.IsOpen())
            {
                CString connectionString = "Driver = " + drv + ";Database=" + db + ";DSN=" + dsn + ";UID=" + user + ";PWD=" + pwd;
                database.OpenEx(connectionString, CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);
                return 0;
            }
```

After opening a connection to my database and successfully doing SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc. I now want to do some prepared statement. Currently I just parse some variables to my methods:

`CString const stmt = "SELECT " + selectValue + " FROM " + tableValue + ";";`.

I am currently using CDatabase and CRecordset for my project.

Here is one method as an example: (please ignore the bool return value^^)

```
bool newWorker(CString table_name, CString values)
    {
        try
        {
            const CString stmt = "INSERT INTO " + table_name + " VALUES (" + values + ");";
            CRecordset rs(&database);
            rs.Open(AFX_DB_USE_DEFAULT_TYPE, _T("SELECT * FROM " + table_name + ";"), CRecordset::none);
            database.ExecuteSQL(stmt);
            rs.Close();
            cout << "Recordset closed!\n";
            return true;
        }
        catch (CException* p)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me how to do prepared statements really simple?

Just ask me when sth is not clear. Still new to stack overflow :) Also ask for more code if you need some more details

I tried using [SQLite3](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html)  (sqlite3_prepare()-method)at first. Is there a way using SQLite for a mssql database? After that I tried '[Prepared Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/prepared-execution-odbc?view=sql-server-ver16)' but I didn't really understand what I am supposed to do with that.

Comment: I think you want a [parameterized query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/data/odbc/recordset-parameterizing-a-recordset-odbc).

Comment: Just a little warning, MFC is kinda old and obsolete! You're supposed to do WinRT stuff these days.